# Launch Image not showing up

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I'm trying to add a launch image to my app using the LaunchScreen.storyboard, however the image isn't showing up. I added an image view, centered it with constraints and then chose my image from the drop down and it shows up in the storyboard. When I launch the app on my device it is not there. Only the labels I added to the storyboard show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you already ran the app on a device without the image and you added it later on. Try uninstalling the app and restart your phone and install it again.